# Designing Raw Data Printing

Tags: c#, printing

I having difficulties when sending Raw Data to receipt printer. I am using Builtin C# (Visual Studio 2008 ,FrameWork 3.5) PrintDocument() function. But it is slow while sending data to printer. And keeps busy my program. So I started to search to overcome this problem and I found [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091). Great article, I can print directly to printer, but I am unable to design. For ex:

```
Quan:  Product Name:         Total:
------------------------------------    
1 x    Product 1             1,5 USD
2 x    Product 2             2,5 USD
------------------------------------
Bill No    : 5126
User       : SomeUser

        THANKS FOR COMING
```

Above design what I want, but I couldn't make it. I read something about ESC code but I couldn't found how to use it properly, and of course WHAT ARE THE ESC CODES. I read lots of article but I couldn't found an example clearly. In a word

HOW TO DESIGN RAW DATA USING ESC CODES

Comment: If you bypass the driver and send raw data, you will have to send it in the format understood by that particular printer.  No one will be able to tell you the escape codes without knowing the exact model number of the printer, there is no universal set (although PCL and Postscript are very widespread).

Answer (score 0):

How about printing the normal way (I assume you had it working how you wanted apart from it blocking your program and being "slow")?  You could simply call the normal print routine from a separate thread (probably just one thread per printer which you could re-use for subsequent jobs).

Comment: I'am already doing it. But Reciept Printer Driver is pain in the a** . And everything gets messy when i use network printers. Windows sends in 2-3 seconds. I'am choosing RAW Printing because i don't want to mess with the Printer Driver. Once and for all solution is RAW DATA PRINTING i think.